# Java Threading Runnable / Callable

Tags: java, multithreading

My current project involves sending network traffic to multiple different hosts via various TCP protocols. I am planning on making it a "plugin" type design where plugins for the different protocols can be written by implementing my interface and added at runtime.

Below is my initial design, I would like some pointers from more experienced developers specifically on if I am threading the correct way, and also how to "talk back" to my Swing GUI.

My Main class is my GUI, it extends JFrame and was created using Netbeans. On a button click I want to load the module (in this instance SSH - les not worry about the loading of the modules I have that done).

The code for the button click is below:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();    
    PluginWorker worker = new PluginWorker();
    executor.execute(worker);    
}
```

So firstly, is there need for this Executor to call my worker? Can I use a SwingWorker here to take the execution away from my Swing GUI?

The following code is my PluginWorker class, it is a class designed to launch the network probing threads, im not sure there is need for it? A SwingWorker may be suitable for this? Also the arraylist of tasks could easily be up to 10,000 in size, so thats why I have chosen to use the invokeAll function? What is best practice for that?

```
public class PluginWorker implements Runnable {
    private final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);  
    private final Collection<GenericPlugin> tasks = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public void run() {

        SshPlugin ssh = new SshPlugin();
        tasks.add(ssh);
        //tasks could easily be up to 10,000 in size, so thats why I have chosen to use the invokeAll function?

        try {            
            es.invokeAll(tasks);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        es.shutdown();
    }    
}
```

Finally, my SshPlugin which I intend can be written by anybody, extends "GenericPlugin" which implements my "Plugin" interface (so I can enforce functions like getAuthor, getDescription, etc) and also implements "Callable". This was needed so I could run the invokeAll from a arraylist. Now my concern is that my plugin is over-engineered, do I really need to extend from GenericPlugin, would it be better for my SSHPlugin to directly implements "plugin" and "callable" itself?

Comment: I'm not sure that the button's actionPerformed() needs to use an Executor.  Probably, but depends how long it takes to create and launch the 10,000 tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer of your Question is that : Whenever you are interacting with GUI and some background task is to be done with continuous updates in GUI then you should use `javax.swing.SwingWorker`. You can get to know how to use `javax.swing.SwingWorker` efficiently and effectively by going through this official tutorial [`Worker Threads and SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: So should I replace my PluginWorker (which implements runnable) with a SwingWorker, but I would still need further threading there at a task level. Is my current approach ok for the second layer of threading?

Comment: So you mean you are executing many threads in sequence after the button is clicked..?

Comment: Yes,potentially 10,000 tasks at the plugin level. So I am aware I need to firstly, get away from the GUI, and secondly, kick off the 10,000 tasks.

Comment: Well Then I will suggest you to carry on executing those tasks in Executor framework .. And whenever in the middle you wish to update GUI use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` so that the GUI is updated in EDT